# How works python's stat module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, stat

I know that a am little bit curious.Because i believe if i go deep , i can get it faster and in a short time i can be expert..Today Some things caught my eye in "stat" module in python 3.7

Sometimes we need status of file or directory.We can see it with like that.

```
>>>import pathlib as ph
>>>x=ph.Path('D://Music')
WindowsPath('D:/Music')
x.is_dir()
True
```

There is no problem.Then i go to inside of pathlib for whats going on inital state.And I knew that i would encounter stat module in it.

if we do this:

```
x.stat()
#Then we will get a tuple like this
os.stat_result(st_mode=16749, st_ino=28147497........
```

So stat module to find out if the given address is a directory or a file takes "st_mode" ,  in this case this number 16749 And magic begins here.

Following codes are from inside of stat module.

Our number (16749) first crossing from S_IFMT , so will be &-ed with value.

```
def S_IMODE(mode):
    """Return the portion of the file's mode that can be set by
    os.chmod().
    """
    return mode & 0o7777

def S_IFMT(mode):
    """Return the portion of the file's mode that describes the
    file type.
    """
    return mode & 0o170000

# Constants used as S_IFMT() for various file types
# (not all are implemented on all systems)

S_IFDIR  = 0o040000  # directory
```

if we do it manually :

```
>>> 16749&0o170000
16384
>>> oct(16384)
'0o40000'     #really is that   S_IFDIR  = 0o040000  # directory
```

It's looking that this value comes from built'in os level ,cause stat tuple of x file returned it (st_mode).So question is this.

1.Where comes these values? like S_IFDIR there a few variabls keeps this "Octal" values like this 0o040000  .

2.Why this octal number & ed , why not or , xor?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: `Where comes these values?` They were lifted from POSIX, which got them from Unix, which probably got them from something slightly before Unix.  In other words, the values are historical, and now permanent, similar to the many magic GUID values in Windows programming.

Comment: Yes really is magic.And i know  encryption's uses xor operation , and here & (and).Really magic tha how they design and found)

Comment: And i also love this peoples ,who can't answer ,  but disLIKING.

Comment: It's not literal magic or something incomprehensible. These values are _called_ "magic numbers" because they were somehow almost randomly picked to mean something in certain contexts, while _by themselves_ they aren't anything special. As for `and`-ing them with some octal numbers, this, as the comments say, retrieves different parts of the number `mode`. Apparently, `mode` can be treated as multiple numbers fused together. You can also try `and`-ing other numbers with these constants to see what this does.